# How to read text and word file in textarea in asp.net using c#

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to read a file for storing the file into a `database`.
When I store any `.txt` file using FileUpload form in database and retrieve it in `TextArea` it displays it's text but when I create text file using `string[]` createtext and store the text in `TextArea` and then i again retreive it back it shows the text in `TextArea` like this

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman;}{\f2\froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman;}{\f3\froman
\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman;}{\f4\froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman;}{\f5\froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman;}{\f6\froman\fcharset2\fprq2{\*\panose 05050102010706020507}Symbol;}{\f7\fnil\fcharset2\fprq2{
\*\panose 05000000000000000000}Wingdings;}{\f8\fnil\fcharset2\fprq2{\*\panose 05020102010507070707}Wingdings 2;}{\f9\fnil\fcharset2\fprq2{\*\panose 05040102010807070707}Wingdings 3;}{\f10\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020b0604020202020204}Arial;}{\f11
\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Arial;}{\f12\fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Arial;}{\f13\fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Arial;}{\f14\fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Arial;}{\f15\fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Arial;}{\f16\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020b0604030504040204}Verdana;}{
\f17\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Verdana;}{\f18\fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Verdana;}{\f19\fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Verdana;}{\f20\fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Verdana;}{\f21\fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Verdana;}{\f22\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{
\*\panose 020b0604030504040204}Tahoma;}{\f23\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Tahoma;}{\f24\fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Tahoma;}{\f25\fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Tahoma;}{\f26\fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Tahoma;}{\f27\fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Tahoma;}}{\colortbl;\red0
\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0
\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;\red135\green135\blue188;\red75\green78\blue179;}{\stylesheet{\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \fs24\cgrid \snext0 Normal;}{\*\cs1
\additive Default Paragraph Font;}{\s2\fs20\cgrid \sbasedon0\snext2 Style 1;}{\s4\f16\fs6\cgrid \sbasedon0\snext4 Style 2;}{\*\cs3\additive\fs20\cgrid  Character Style 2;}{\*\cs5\additive\f16\fs6\cgrid  Character Style 1;}}
{\info{\version1}{\creatim\yr2014\mo7\dy2\hr6\min23}}\paperw3648\paperh3840\margl448\margr449\margt0\margb157\deftab720\widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\formshade\viewkind1\viewscale100\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot\fet0\useltbaln\jexpand\noxlattoyen\expshrtn\noultrlspc
\dntblnsbdb\nospaceforul\horzdoc\ftnlytwnine\htmautsp\nolnhtadjtbl\useltbaln\alntblind\lytcalctblwd\lyttblrtgr\lnbrkrule\nobrkwrptbl\snaptogridincell\allowfieldendsel\wrppunct\asianbrkrule\newtblstyruls\nogrowautofit\sectd\stextflow0\margrsxn389
\margbsxn127\linex0\sectdefaultcl\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \fs24\cgrid {{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpbxpage\shpbxignore\shpbypage\shpbyignore\shpleft21\shptop0\shpright3669\shpbottom3840\shpfhdr0\shpwr3\shpfblwtxt1\shpz1
\shplid1027{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 202}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn posrelh}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn posrelv}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn dxTextLeft}{\sv 36576}}{\sp{\sn dyTextTop}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxTextRight}{\sv 36576}}{\sp{\sn dyTextBottom}{
\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFilled}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineType}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineWidth}{\sv 3175}}{\sp{\sn lineColor}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fLine}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fBehindDocument}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fBackground}{\sv 1}}{\shptxt \pard\plain\widctlpar\adjustright \fs20\cgrid 
{\par }}}}}\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \fs24\cgrid {{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpbxcolumn\shpbxignore\shpbypara\shpbyignore\shpleft2755\shptop158\shpright2755\shpbottom673\shpfhdr0\shpwr2\shpwrk0\shpfblwtxt0\shpz2\shplid1028{\sp{
\sn shapeType}{\sv 20}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn posrelh}{\sv 2}}{\sp{\sn posrelv}{\sv 2}}{\sp{\sn shapePath}{\sv 4}}{\sp{\sn fFillOK}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFilled}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineWidth}{\sv 3175}}{\sp{\sn fArrowheadsOK}{
\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fBehindDocument}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistLeft}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistTop}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistRight}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistBottom}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineColor}{\sv 7237491}}}}}\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap
\adjustright \fs24\cgrid {{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpbxcolumn\shpbxignore\shpbypara\shpbyignore\shpleft2184\shptop158\shpright2184\shpbottom678\shpfhdr0\shpwr2\shpwrk0\shpfblwtxt0\shpz3\shplid1029{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 20}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{
\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn posrelh}{\sv 2}}{\sp{\sn posrelv}{\sv 2}}{\sp{\sn shapePath}{\sv 4}}{\sp{\sn fFillOK}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFilled}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineWidth}{\sv 6350}}{\sp{\sn fArrowheadsOK}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fBehindDocument}{\sv 0}}{\sp{
\sn dxWrapDistLeft}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistTop}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistRight}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistBottom}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineColor}{\sv 12369086}}}}}\pard\plain \s2\sb468\sa72\sl208\slmult1\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \cs3
\f10\fs14\expnd-1\expndtw-8\charscalex110\cgrid {RACHEL GARNER
\par }\pard\plain \nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \fs24\cgrid {{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpbxpage\shpbxignore\shpbypage\shpbyignore\shpleft2661\shptop696\shpright3200\shpbottom696\shpfhdr0\shpwr2\shpwrk0\shpfblwtxt0\shpz4\shplid1030{\sp{
\sn shapeType}{\sv 20}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn posrelh}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn posrelv}{\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn shapePath}{\sv 4}}{\sp{\sn fFillOK}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFilled}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineWidth}{\sv 3175}}{\sp{\sn fArrowheadsOK}{
\sv 1}}{\sp{\sn fBehindDocument}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistLeft}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistTop}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistRight}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn dxWrapDistBottom}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn lineColor}{\sv 8619143}}}}}\pard\plain \s2\sb72\sl-185\slmult0\nowidctlpar
\tqr\tx1762\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \cs3\f10\fs24\expnd-1\expndtw-6\charscalex120\cgrid {7}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid s:al Statement\tab }{\f16\fs6\expnd0\expndtw-4\charscalex100\cgrid Exp\'84ienced
\par }\pard \s2\li864\sa36\nowidctlpar\tqr\tx1762\tqr\tx2496\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \f16\fs6\expnd0\expndtw0\charscalex100\cgrid {\tab n\tab Is }{\f22\super\cgrid h}{a:
\par }\pard \s4\li72\sl199\slmult1\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \plain \cs5\f16\fs6\expnd-2\expndtw-10\cgrid {07345 735880
\par }\li0\sl240\slmult1\nowidctlpar\adjustright \f10\expnd-2\expndtw-13\super\charscalex300\cgrid {1}{\f16\nosupersub\charscalex100\cgrid 1 01223 486777
\par }\pard \s4\li72\sl264\slmult1\nowidctlpar\tqr\tx2703\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \f16\expnd0\expndtw-2\nosupersub\charscalex100\cgrid {ra.elgarner@grnall }{\f10\cgrid COM\tab }{\expnd0\expndtw2\cgrid "":r=eorrong
\par }\pard \s2\sl429\slmult1\nowidctlpar\tqr\tx1762\tqr\tx2693\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \plain \cs3\f16\fs6\expnd0\expndtw-1\cgrid {YV}{\f22\cf17\cgrid  =my}{\f10\cf18\cgrid  google}{\f22\cf17\cgrid  coin}{\tab }{\expnd-1\expndtw-6\cgrid 071::
:anp\tab }{\expnd0\expndtw-3\cgrid pbye ofthe Mont 1999}{\f22\expnd0\expndtw-3\super\cgrid '}{\expnd0\expndtw-3\cgrid for
\par }\pard \s2\sb684\sl266\slmult1\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \f22\expnd0\expndtw-2\charscalex120\cgrid {Key }{\f16\charscalex100\cgrid Skills
\par }\pard \s2\sb216\sa216\sl194\slmult1\nowidctlpar\tx1344\tqr\tx2746\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \fs15\expnd-1\expndtw-8\charscalex95\cgrid {V}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid e}{\fs6\super\charscalex100\cgrid '}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid r}{
\fs6\super\charscalex100\cgrid t}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid r}{\fs6\super\charscalex100\cgrid '}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid rt}{\fs6\super\charscalex100\cgrid g}{\f16\fs6\charscalex100\cgrid ate,\tab }{\f16\fs6\expnd2\expndtw14\charscalex100\cgrid 
\'95 '''}{\fs6\expnd2\expndtw14\super\charscalex100\cgrid \'95}{\f16\fs6\expnd2\expndtw14\charscalex100\cgrid ''}{\fs6\expnd2\expndtw14\super\charscalex100\cgrid ...E\'95PeM}{\f16\fs6\expnd2\expndtw14\charscalex100\cgrid  \'95\tab \'95rn.9.nerl
\par }\pard \s4\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \plain \cs5\f16\fs6\expnd0\expndtw-1\cgrid {Work Experience
\par }\pard \s2\sl194\slmult1\nowidctlpar\aspalpha\aspnum\nocwrap\adjustright \plain \cs3\fs23\expnd-4\expndtw-22\cgrid {iFi}{\f16\expnd-2\expndtw-12\sub\charscalex110\cgrid r}{\f22\fs11\expnd-2\expndtw-12\cgrid Ftms
\par }\pard\plain}This is extra text
```

Can any one tell me how to convert this in simple text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();  
    string rtfText = ""Your-text-as-in-question;
    rtBox.Rtf = rtfText;
    string plainText = rtBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit`](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx) `HTMLEditorExtender` on your TextBox.

And for convert formated text to plain text use ConvertText method:

```
public string ConvertText(string formatedText)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formatedText))
    {
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(formatedText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        result = result.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
    }
    return result == null ? null : result.Trim();
}
```